# Create a SQL FUNCTION with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, function, codeigniter

For a legacy project, I would like to execute this query using CodeIgniter :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `getCustomerFullName`(intCustomerID INT) 
  RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
  return CONCAT(
    (SELECT FirstName FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = intCustomerID),
    ' ',
    (SELECT LastName FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = intCustomerID))$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to use `$this->db->query()`, I get this error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'DELIMITER $$ CREATE FUNCTION `getCustomerFullName`(intCustomerID INT) RETURNS '
at line 1
```

How can I execute such "multi-line" query using CodeIgniter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the query, not CodeIgniter. Use the regular delimiter inside your function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `getCustomerFullName`(intCustomerID INT) 
  RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
  return CONCAT(
    (SELECT FirstName FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = intCustomerID),
    ' ',
    (SELECT LastName FROM Customer WHERE CustomerID = intCustomerID));
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: it is possible to call a function in codeigniter sql query?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to execute a Function or SP, you need to add this to mysql (in the mtop menu of your phpmyadmin or Workbench) you have many otions

```
in More (routine / new / add new)
create a function or sp
```

Then in CI you only call like

```
$this->db->query('call Function()');
```

Comment: No. I need to create the function IN CodeIgniter. I'm using its migration mechanism, and a lot of different instances. I cannot use PhpMyAdmin in that case, it would require too much maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i get was looking inside system libs and use it.

```
$this->db->simple_query("YOUR FULL SQL STRING");
```

I was looking on google and not solution provided.